# Error Loading Devise Gem Because of Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I am getting an error loading the devise gem:

> ```
> Boot Error
>
> Something went wrong while loading config.ru
>
> Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem 'devise (~> 3.5.1) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this
> ```
>
> machine.
>
> ```
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:347:in
> ```
>
> `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:325:in`
>   each'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:325:in
>   `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:198:in`
>   start'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:182:in
>   `resolve'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in`
>   resolve'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in
>   `specs'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in`
>   specs_for'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in
>   `requested_specs'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in`
>   requested_specs'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in
>   `setup'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler.rb:127:in`
>   setup'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.5/lib/bundler.rb:134:in
>   `require' /Users/Pabi/code/fwitter/config/environment.rb:2:in`'
>   /Users/Pabi/code/fwitter/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in
>   `require_relative'
>   /Users/Pabi/code/fwitter/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in`
>   ' config.ru:1:in `require_relative' config.ru:1:in`
>   block in inner_app'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in
>   `instance_eval'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`
>   initialize' config.ru:1:in `new' config.ru:1:in`inner_app'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:112:in
>   `eval'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:112:in`
>   inner_app'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:102:in
>   `assemble_app'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:86:in`
>   proceed_as_child'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:31:in
>   `call!'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:18:in`
>   call'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/favicon.rb:12:in
>   `call'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/static.rb:14:in`
>   call'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in
>   `call'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`
>   service'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`
>   run'
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in
>   `block in start_thread'

This is what I have in my gems file:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "rake"
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.1'
gem "rack-ssl-enforcer"
gem "haml"


group :development do
  gem "pry"
  gem "shotgun"
  gem "tux"
  gem "sqlite3"
end
```

I don't know what it could be. I did bundle install and it installed the devise gem. When I remove devise everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

The problem was with install one of the dependencies for devise: nokogiri.

I followed [this guide](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#mac_os_x) for installing nokogiri and trouble shooting and it is now resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried just using gem 'devise'? As in:

```
gem 'devise'
```

Ver 3.5.1 is current (as of this writing) so it should install the latest version by default (unless there's a reason you're doing it that way that I've missed).

Comment: I get this ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command devise. And when I try to bundle update I get this Error: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries...

Comment: How would I uninstall all gems completely from my computer?

Answer (score 1):

It is error with config.ru
Bundler cannot find the gem devise 3.5.1
So,Try running `bundle update`